# Whice configuration is better ? configure FastCGI module on IIS for a django web app using wfastcgi.exe or python.exe with an argument wfastcgi.py

Tags: python, django, windows, iis, wfastcgi

So I have been learning to deploy a django web application on IIS Web Server. I had successfully deployed it. However, when configuring FastCgiModule on handler mapping, I noticed that the requested executable optional are **.dll** or **.exe** file.

[capture of the requested file for FastCgiModule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3uJV.png)

But, I have read some tutorials and all of them **are not** using .dll or .exe file on their FastCgiModule, instead they use

```
'path to python.exe'|'path to wfastcgi.py'
```

this way works. Then I tried another way to configure this using

```
'path to wfastcgi.py'
```

and it also works.

So I have surfed on internet a few days but I couldn't find the  answer which way is better.

Comment: https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-django-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ HttpPlatformHandler is your only option to go as wfastcgi has been deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

You should use wfastcgi.exe, python.exe is used to run python, not to configure FastCgiModule on iis.

You can also refer to this link, which also uses wfastcgi.py in web.config：

https://pypi.org/project/wfastcgi.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using virtual environments it's better to use:

```
path\to\env\python.exe|path\to\env\wfastcgi.py
```

If you just call `path\to\env\wfastcgi.py` it will be using your globally installed Python, assuming you have Python installed globally.

This could cause problems if you decide to upgrade the global Python version and not your environment.